# Pulsations in massive stars

Tags: star

Why are tidally induced pulsations not typical for massive binary stars? For which kind of binaries they are typical? I read it in the last but one paragraph in Discussion of https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/809/2/134/pdf .